# Is there a (plural/singular) naming convention for ViewModel properties bound to multiple controls?

Tags: naming-conventions

Most important is that a property name reveals it's purpose. But on the other hand I'd like correct naming as well (adhere to conventions). So my question is not meant to start an endless debate, but I'd like to know if there are any generally accepted conventions for this.

So if my ViewModel contains one property that is bound to the IsVisible property of all buttons on a page, should the property then best be named AreButtonsVisible or IsButtonsVisible?

I could not find any information about this on Micrsoft's Naming Guidelines.